# Difference between two multiband Sentinel-2 images

Tags: gdal, sentinel-2, machine-learning

So I was using ml4floods, a machine learning tool in python to detect flooded areas in satellite imagery. The input it takes is a 13 band Sentinel 2 (L1-C) image.

I ran the model on the Sentinel 2 image used in the demo taken from the World Floods Database. It gave the correct results.

But when I downloaded Sentinel 2 imagery from Sentinel Dataspace hub, it was available as 13 separate bands as TIFFs zipped together. I unpacked them and ran gdal_mergy.py -separate band1.tif band2.tif ... to make a 13 band composite and finally ran the model on the result. The model was not expecting it and threw an invalid data error.

Can anyone guess (by gdalinfo-ing my images or otherwise) anything wrong with my process?

The demo GeoTIFF which works fine is this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoYnbgucZp2wiyIqcwj0SmOebDta?e=AvAyn4

gdalinfo metadata:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: EMSR287_05MAGWITZ_DEL_v1_observed_event_a.tif
Size is 1602, 798
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (12.047216443798490,50.463040748470945)
Pixel Size = (0.000089831528412,-0.000089831528412)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  12.0472164,  50.4630407) ( 12d 2'49.98"E, 50d27'46.95"N)
Lower Left  (  12.0472164,  50.3913552) ( 12d 2'49.98"E, 50d23'28.88"N)
Upper Right (  12.1911266,  50.4630407) ( 12d11'28.06"E, 50d27'46.95"N)
Lower Right (  12.1911266,  50.3913552) ( 12d11'28.06"E, 50d23'28.88"N)
Center      (  12.1191715,  50.4271980) ( 12d 7' 9.02"E, 50d25'37.91"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = B1_first
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B2_first
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B3_first
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B4_first
Band 5 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B5_first
Band 6 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B6_first
Band 7 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B7_first
Band 8 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B8_first
Band 9 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B8A_first
Band 10 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B9_first
Band 11 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B10_first
Band 12 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B11_first
Band 13 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B12_first
```

The raw s2 band TIFFs I get from dataspace hub is this:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoYnbgucZp2wiyFYAemdgMn7-NAB?e=hfi42I

The final composite I make from the raw bands is this:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoYnbgucZp2wiyAzLG5BAZWwPMiI?e=SUXpda

gdalinfo metadata:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: merged.tif
Size is 2212, 2500
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (66.997580999999997,28.014191000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.000460280741410,-0.000408084800000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  66.9975810,  28.0141910) ( 66d59'51.29"E, 28d 0'51.09"N)
Lower Left  (  66.9975810,  26.9939790) ( 66d59'51.29"E, 26d59'38.32"N)
Upper Right (  68.0157220,  28.0141910) ( 68d 0'56.60"E, 28d 0'51.09"N)
Lower Right (  68.0157220,  26.9939790) ( 68d 0'56.60"E, 26d59'38.32"N)
Center      (  67.5066515,  27.5040850) ( 67d30'23.95"E, 27d30'14.71"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 5 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 6 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 7 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 8 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 9 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 10 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 11 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 12 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 13 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

Comment: It people have to follow links to get to data, they are much less likely to do so. You should provide metadata/statistics in the body of the Question to get an answer. You might even identify the problem by collecting the metadata.

Comment: I had already scoured through the metadata to try find any difference but couldn't. Edited my post to include it.